# RecyclerView - No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I know this question has already been posted but i tried all solutions and the error still exists.when i call fragment which is loading some data from `json` and set it in `recyclerview`, with **Debug app** i get this error

> RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

**Fragement** :

```
public class Artists extends  Fragment {
    String URL_DATA = JsonData.FirebaseList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ProgressBar pb;
    private List<Post_Artist> post_artists;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView loading;
    private AdapterFor_Artists adapter;
    private AdView mAdView;

    public Artists() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artists, container, false);
        post_artists = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rc);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        loading = v.findViewById(R.id.loadingtext);
        pb = v.findViewById(R.id.loadingP);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"ARCADECLASSIC.TTF");
        loading.setTypeface(typeface);
        if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new AdapterFor_Artists(post_artists, getActivity(), new RecyclerViewClickListenner_ForArtist() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, Post_Artist post_artist) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArtistsPage.class);
                intent.putExtra("json_url", post_artist.getJsonUrl());
                intent.putExtra("name", post_artist.getArtistName());
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        checkInternet();
        return v;
    }

    private boolean checkInternet() {
        if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
            showDialog();

            return false;
        } else {
            refreshContent();
        }
        return true;
    }



    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectionManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    private void refreshContent() {
        fetchRemoteData(new DataStatus_For_ArtistsList() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Post_Artist> post_artists) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    adapter.getItems().clear();
                    adapter.getItems().addAll(post_artists);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                msgError();
            }
        });
    }


    }
    private void fetchRemoteData(final DataStatus_For_ArtistsList callback) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        List<Post_Artist> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("bgs");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                Post_Artist item = new Post_Artist(
                                        o.optString("json_url"),
                                        o.optString("name"),
                                        o.optString("cover")

                                );
                                listItems.add(item);
                            }
                            callback.onSuccess(listItems);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        callback.onError(error);

                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Create & set the adapter in `onCreateView`, with no items. In your network response handler, add the items to the existing adapter.

Comment: @siger please see my update post

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the adapter with your post_artists list in the onCreateView().your adapter is null that's why you have this error.